# return records of multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have this array

```
 array(5) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "REFER" [1]=> string(12) "Não Sócios" } 
    [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "REFER" [1]=> string(12) "Não Sócios" } 
    [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "REFER" [1]=> string(12) "Não Sócios" } 
    [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "REFER" [1]=> string(12) "Não Sócios" } 
    [4]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "REFER" [1]=> string(12) "Não Sócios" } 
}
```

and wanted to search the database to find the ids of these "elements" and build an array like the example below.

```
$array_ids = ("1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2");
```

that is, i want to create a simple array with the values returned from the database.

is this possible to do? and if so, how can i do it?

i've manage to return the records like this

```
for($i=0; $i<count($subsgroup); $i++) {
    for($j=0; $j<count($subsgroup[$i]); $j++) {
        $sql_groups = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM $table_name WHERE name = %s", $subsgroup[$i][$j]);
        $rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql_groups);
        foreach($rows as $r) {
            echo $r->id.', ';
        }
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

this will output something like this

```
1, 2,
1, 2,
1, 2,
1, 2,
1, 2,
```

how can i put those returned records in an array like

```
$array_ids = ("1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2", "1,2");
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: `implode(',', $row)`

Comment: just make `$array_ids = array()` then when you loop through in your function just push that info to the new array `array_push(DATA,ARRAY)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array_ids = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($subsgroup); $i++) {
    $ids = array();
    for($j=0; $j<count($subsgroup[$i]); $j++) {
        $sql_groups = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM $table_name WHERE name = %s", $subsgroup[$i][$j]);
        $rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql_groups);
        foreach($rows as $r) {
            array_push($ids, $r->id);
        }
    }
    array_push( $array_ids , implode(',', $ids) );
}
```

Here i'm creating `$ids` array in the inner loop, and on each query i'm appending the `id`s from the database to that array.

After each iteration i'm appending the `$ids` array to the parent `$array_ids` array and glue the elements inside `$ids` using `implode`.

Answer (score 0):

You should NEVER put a query in a loop - it could cause a lot of troubles. If i understood your problem i guess you can do something like :

```
$sql_groups = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM $table_name WHERE name = 
%s", $subsgroup[$i][$j]);
$rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql_groups);
$array_ids = [];
foreach($rows as $key=>$val){
$array_ids[]=$key;
}

echo $array_ids
```